# Supremum of $\sqrt{n} -\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor $

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I've got the following question:

$A = \{\sqrt{n} - \left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Find inf A, sup A

---

inf A is no big deal, but I have a hard time proving sup A is 1

I've tried to prove that:
$\sqrt{n^2 - 1} -\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2-1}\right\rfloor > \sqrt{n} -\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor $

but couldn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously
$$\sqrt n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor<1.$$

Then for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find $n=m^2-1^*$ such that

$$1-\epsilon<\sqrt n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor=\sqrt{m^2-1}-(m-1).$$

This occurs when

$$\sqrt{m^2-1}>m-\epsilon$$ or

$$2m>\frac1\epsilon+\epsilon$$ which is always possible.

$^*$Chosen to be the closest to a perfect square.

---

For example, with $\epsilon=0.0001$, $m=5001>5000.00005$ yields

$$\sqrt{25010000}-\lfloor\sqrt{25010000}\rfloor\approx0.999900019995>0.9999.$$

Comment: Why are we considering integers of the form $m^2-1$..?

Answer (score 3):

For $n=m^2-1$, we have $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor=m-1$, and

$$1-\left(\sqrt{n}-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\right)=m-\sqrt{m^2-1}=\frac1{m+\sqrt{m^2-1}}.$$

This expression has the limit $0$.

Comment: Yves.Very nice!!

Answer (score 0):

We will choose to consider integers of the form $n^2-1$. Because
$$\sqrt {n^2-1}/n\to 1$$
we can make $\sqrt {n^2-1}$ as close to $n $ as we like provided we make $n $ large enough. We also know that $\sqrt {n^2-1}<n $ and we see that we can make
$$\sqrt {n^2-1}-\lfloor\sqrt {n^2-1}\rfloor$$
as close to one as we like. It is also clear that it can't be greater than one.