# find $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $a_n=\{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ $n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

> I have to find $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $a_n=\{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor : n \in\mathbb{N}\}$

I suppose that I have to relate to subsequences  .
First one is $a_{n_k}$ for all n that maintains $\sqrt n\in\mathbb {N}$ , so the limit is $0$.

Second  one $a_{n_j}$ includes the rest of the elements.I suppose it converges to 1, but dont know how to prove it.

Comment: What's a subseries?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I guess subsequence

Comment: Yes, thank you. My english is no so great, espetially in math terminilogy

Comment: I dont understand lim sup or lim inf.

Comment: Gimusi.Have a look at the link where Yves answers this question, in particular his shorter answer.Vow!:)Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$a_n=\{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor \ge 0$$

and for $n=m^2 \implies a_n=0$ then $\liminf a_n =0$.

For $\limsup$ we have

$$a_n=\{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor \le 1$$

and for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find $n=m^2-1$ such that $\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor=1-\epsilon$.

Comment: That is exacly what Im asking. I have already found lim inf but, has no idea about lim sup

Comment: You might notice that a possible duplicate target has been pointed out in the meantime. Your approach is essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2015624.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I see that now!